# google sheets: average last 3 numbers in a column of numbers when some cells are empty

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, offset

in a data set I have rows (dates) with numbers in some of them. I want a running average of only the las 3 numbers. I've tried FILTER, and then COUNTA, OFFSET, but this doesn't seem to work without manual manipulation.

"AVERAGE(OFFSET($H$29:$H$37,counta(FILTER($B$1:$B$16,$B$1:$B$16 >0))-5,0,5))
I used this to average only last 5 values

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=AVERAGE(SORTN(FILTER(B76:B, B76:B<>""), 5, 1, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B76:B)), 0))
```

[image]